# Assign a string to a RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to input a predefined string into a RichTextBox during the process of a method, e.g.:

```
"various words" = RichTextBox1,ToString;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of language are you using?  It isn't C#.

Comment: You need to learn much more and more simple things in C# then RichTextBox

Comment: Learn the BASICS before going into GUI Dev. "" = x What kind of statement is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx).

Example:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "various words";
```

If you need the text to be richly formatted, you need the [`Rtf` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) instead.

Example:

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi Hello in \b bold-face \b0 .}";
```